# R: Date format when writing a zoo object to a file?

Tags: r, time, format, zoo

I've been playing for a while with zoo package.
I can read files using the `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`  option

But how can I use this option when writing the results back to the disk?
I mean, the default format seems to be 
`"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`

and I need to be `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`

Where can I change it?

cheers

Comment: Be more specific : What's the nature of the index : Date, chron, Posixlt, Posixct,... ? Do you want to write to a text file or a binary file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean.

however, when I have dates that look like `d/m/y` I use the following

```
Day <- format(strptime(a$DATE, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d")
```

Note this does not  use the `zoo`  package, just  `base` functionality

Comment: Hi, finally what I do is converting the index from chron to POSIXct, that looks much better when writtn to a file or printed